# How to encrypt my program config file using PowerShell to prevent users from seen the content?

Tags: arrays, powershell, file, encryption, text

I have a small config file for a program that this code creates, the file is created by converting the `$Data` variable into Json format txt file and reads back from it.
I would like the file to be encrypted and still be able to decrypt and read from it.

```
$path = "test.txt"

$Data = @{
   File = "test.exe"
   Folder = "c:\temp\"
   count = "4"  
}

$Data | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content  -Path $path
$NewData = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$NewData.File
$NewData.Folder
$NewData.count
```

Any suggestions on how to add simple encryption and decryption?
Maybe using `ConvertTo-SecureString`.. I tried but cant get it to work (not even close).

Comment: Start by identifying which (kind of) attacker you're trying to protect it from.

Comment: Do you want to prevent tampering or prevent anyone knowing what's in it? Or both?

Comment: The easiest resource I can imagine is [`Export-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7.1), the file can only be read by your user and only on the computer it was exported.

Comment: Good one @Santiago. I didn't know that one. Have some scripts to update now.

Comment: @alexzelaya encryption on xml files with `Export-CliXml` only works with PSCredential objects tho, and if I'm not mistaken, on `SecureStrings` (untested, not on a domain computer right now). If you have the possibility to test it, let me know please :) just create a secure string and export it. Then try to import it with a different user or on a different computer, if you see the `Key not valid for use in specified state`, then it works!

Comment: The idea is to simply make the config file idiot proof. The program i am writing is a small tool that will help some of my "computer literate" colleagues and i dont want them to try and edit it.

Comment: Santiago Squarzon thank you soo much. I will definitely try it tomorrow. Sounds like a promising way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank @santiago-squarzon and all who contributed to this post.

After a VERY long night of trial and error basically attempting to translate the Microsoft c# examples and snippets to PowerShell I finally found a working solution.

Also a big thank you to

- Luke Orellana for this article https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/encrypt-password-powershell/
- Adam Bertram for this eye opening article https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/07/20/save-and-read-sensitive-data-with-powershell.aspx

Here is the final solution for anyone that wants to do it like me!

```
$tempfolder = $env:temp
$tmpkey = {110
52
114
225
64
235
208
235
242
44
101
16
80
94
97
252} | Set-Content $tempfolder\newkey.key     # I have generated this 16 byte random key using key generation script 
                                              # with the help from " https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/encrypt-password-powershell/ ""
$key = Get-Content $tempfolder\newkey.key 


$file = "test.txt"

$Data = @{
   File = "test.exe"
   Folder = "c:\temp\"
   count = "4"  
}

$perm = $data | ConvertTo-Json
$perm |  ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $key |  Set-Content -Path $file

#  this encrypted the data into my test.txt file no to show how it looks inside
$tmp = Get-Content -path $file
echo $tmp


#  now to retrieve it and convert back to usable text
  
$NewData = Get-Content  -Path $file | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key
$LoadedData = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR((($NewData)))) | ConvertFrom-Json
$LoadedData.File
$LoadedData.Folder
$LoadedData.Count
```